# CSS ID's and Classes defined on one element if there are children which one is the parent?

Tags: subclass, css

Given a structure like:

```
<div class="Stargate" id="MGM"> 
   <div class="SG1">
   </div>
   <div id="Atlantis">
   </div> 
</div>
```

What will be SG1's and Atlantis' parent Stargate or MGM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference, both `Stargate` and `MGM` is on the same parent `div`. But you'll find `MGM` to be the "better" or "stronger" of the two ways of identifying that `div`.

With "better/stronger" I mean that the `id` will have implications in CSS/javascript, for example, in CSS the id is stronger.

```
#MGM .SG1 {
    /* very strong selector */
}

.Stargate .SG1 {
    /* not so strong selector */
}
```

In javascript you have

```
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('MGM');
```

where the `document.getElementById` is widely supported whilst the corresponding `document.getElementsByClassName` is a relatively new addition to modern browsers.

Comment: That's what I thought! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No worries. I'll just thought of clarifying further. I'll make an edit.